# How to convert date string to another format in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I have a date picker that only adds date for that date I want to add time string and convert it to date.

```
fromString = @"00:00:00";
NSString *fromDate = [fromdate.text stringByAppendingString:@" "];
fromDate = [fromDate fromString];
NSDate *currentDate = [self dateFromString:fromDate withFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+5.30"]];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentDate];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *date = [self dateFromString: dateString withFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *fromDate1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%.0f000%@)/", [date timeIntervalSince1970],[formatter stringFromDate:date]];
```

My Problem is that I'm getting 5.30 extra time when converting to string.

Comment: There is nothing related to JSON in your code. JSON has no format for date. However, I guess that you want to set zero timezone on your formatter. Not sure why are you converting date to string and viceversa three times.

Comment: I've edited your code changing the variable names to follow standard naming conventions so the syntax coloring works, making it easier to read. It is best if you follow these conventions.

Comment: jsonDate:
/Date(1522607400000+0530)/
 I want this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Problem is that I'm getting 5.30 extra time when converting to string.

To convert from string initially you use:

```
NSDate *CurrentDate = [self dateFromString:fROMDATE withFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

You do not give the code for `dateFromString` but at a guess this routine is using the GMT/UTC time zone for the conversion.

To convert back to a string you first do:

```
[DATEFORMATER setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+5.30"]];
```

And so if your original time was converted from a string as GMT your `DATE_STRING` will show a time 5.5 hours "later" (the same time point in GMT, just displayed as it is in the GMT+5.30 time zone).

HTH

Comment: jsonDate:
/Date(1522607400000+0530)/

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *finalDate = ……

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterTime = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSLocale *location = [NSLocale currentLocale];

NSString *country = [location localeIdentifier];

NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:country];

[dateFormatterTime setLocale:locale];

[dateFormatterTime setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *timeZone = [dateFormatterTime dateFromString:finalDate];

[dateFormatterTime setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];

NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"]; // set as you wish

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:timeZone];

NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:timeZone];

NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

// get final date in LocalTimeZone
NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:timeZone];
```

NSLog(@“your NSDate = %@ ”, destinationDate );

Comment: I don't understand please check my question

Comment: in your code where did you convert date to Json String I want that converted string

Comment: Hello Dinesh , Now check above answer!